# System-level, mixed signal hardware description language (HDL) and software (editor, simulator)?

Tags: simulation, hdl, eda

I am looking for devices (conceptual / software) to simplify and unify our current method of industrial control system planning and documentation, especially to help with debugging.
This is currently a collection of different systems and files, i.e. system-level graphics, signal spreadsheets for interfaces, schematics (system-level electrical planning, components), ...
Unfortunately, the complexity of the design cannot be reduced.

The solution should allow hierarchical capture of system (controllers, sensors, actuators, wire, connectors, ...) and component schematics (internals like switches, amplifiers) and ideally allow tracing of signals through elements (across nets).

Ideally this could reduce the number of manually created documents and generate the respective output "views".

I thought of an object-oriented approach (signals, pins, nodes, signal level modifiers, groups) that would allow building such system but that would be very likely reinventing the wheel, and also would be quite an undertaking, especially with regard to the graphical interface.

However, I did not find existing software for the task so far; I am probably not searching with the right keywords. HDL mostly returns logic/chip level design software. While SPICE is for simulation, it is too specialized for my task. EDA (Altium, Eagle, KiCad,  ..) or electrical planning software does not provide simulation features to my knowledge (it could be used to graphically create netlists to work with, though).

I've now discovered [SystemC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemC) and [Electronic system-level design and verification (ESL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_system-level_design_and_verification) which leads to [EDA software firms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_design_automation#Companies) which seem to focus on chip-level design software but also feature system level electrical planning (and apparently also simulation, but I'll have to research that further).

What are the proper terms or standards to search for?

Answer (score 0):

PLC communication is defined in volumes of IEC standards developed over the last 40 yrs of evolution at every level of the ISO model in great detail including; standardized graphic consolidation of different systems; software, hardware, security and error handling.

Start reading from;

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_61131
http://www.plcopen.org/pages/tc4_communication/

Then look for the answers you seek.  Like most communication standards, the related documents could fill a room.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to spend the money there are commercial solutions to this, like matlab and simulink and more particularly their HDL verifier tool. They even have a tool that will let you verify HDL code, then compile it to an FPGA

In most places I've worked the simulation is done on different pieces of software. For example: a control loop would be evalulated in Matlab, octave, or labview for a stability check, then implemented in spice or simulink to verify its operation in the time domain. Then finally implemented in hardware.

[VHDL-AMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHDL-AMS) is another language that bridges the gap between digital and analog, however the tools are very expensive.

Another way I have verified HDL in the past is to use text files and a test bench that simulates an ADC with a text file as an input and the text file can come from any source, even actual values from ADC's.

There is not really any tools that will do everything you describe, so if you have the time to roll you own then go for it.